# I'm in trouble with the adding metrics and saving model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to add the custom metrics and save the model based on the following code.
[segmentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation)

I don't know how to make the above code.

I tried to make it but the following error has occurred.

```
Unable to restore custom object of type _tf_keras_metric currently. Please make sure that the layer implements `get_config`and `from_config` when saving. In addition, please use the `custom_objects` arg when calling `load_model()`.
```

Code:

```
# metric part
def precision(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = K.ones_like(y_true) 
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision

# compile part
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy', precision])

# save part
model.save('mymodel')
```

Comment: If you don't train to save the model, where do you get the parameters. Why isn't your evaluation function calculated by tensor

Comment: Acutually, I trained the model  between compile part and save part.
But I omitted the code in the question.

Comment: You are using a custom object 'precision' (as a metric) which needs to be included separately. Are you getting this error while saving the model or while you load it?

Comment: I'm getting this error while saving.
If there is no custom metric, this code don't have the error.

Comment: You rewrite your custom code with tensor.

Comment: I tried to implement with reference to the following page but it doesn't work well.

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize

Comment: I helped you find custom evaluation indicators：https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate

Comment: Thank you!!
I really appreciate it.
I will try to implement it by referring to the page.

Comment: Can you try with    model.save("mymodel.h5") ?